# Woocommerce Display Termmeta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code to display term metadata but for some reason, it's not showing up / Data is blank Sorry for not making it clear the first time

**UPDATED**

```
    if ( 'new_column2' == $column_name ) {
/*Begin*/
foreach((get_term_meta( $post->ID, 'crosssell' )) as $category) {
    $cat_name = $category->name . '</br>';
    $cat_id = $category->term_id . '</br>';
    $crosssell = get_term_meta( $cat_id, 'crosssell', true );
    }
/*End*/
    
 $value = $crosssell;
 }
 return $value;
 }
```

what am i doing wrong

Comment: `it's not showing up` what you mean

Comment: its blank no data is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the problem I had.

```
if ( 'new_column2' == $column_name ) {
/*Begin*/
    
     $prod_cat_args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat', //woocommerce
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'empty'        => 0
);

//$woo_categories = get_categories( $prod_cat_args );
$woo_categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
    $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
    $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name
}
    $cat_term_id = $woo_cat_id;
    $crosssell = get_term_meta( $cat_term_id, 'crosssell', true );
/*End*/
    
 $value = $crosssell;
    }
 return $value;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning variables but not actually outputting anything.

```
foreach( ( get_term_meta( $post->ID, 'crosssell' ) ) as $category ) {
    echo $category->name . '</br>';
    echo $category->term_id . '</br>';
    echo get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'crosssell', true );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I have updated my Question to make it more clear, my output is as follows for  $crosssell = get_term_meta( $cat_id, 'crosssell', true ); then $value = $crosssell; then value gets return $value; and still its blank but if I look at the mysql I get data

Comment: If I do the same with $category->name it shows and the same with $category->term_id. it shows up as it should but for some reason $crosssell = get_term_meta( $category->term_id, 'crosssell', true ); does not